# How to delete a "chapter" in ToC which comes from \printpagenotes

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir, endnotes

So I have a document in `memoir` that uses both footnotes and endnotes. The endnotes are generated through the `\makepagenote` preamble, and `\printpagenotes`

The problem is that in the `ToC`, and the header, it says "Chapter #" -- but its not a chapter! It's the notes. Whats the easiest way to make it act like a section*?

I tried `\printpagenotes*`, but that didn't work, nor did it when I put it after every chapter (which isn't what I want.)

Dissertation is due before my advisor gets on a plane tomorrow at 8pm CET. Just saying, its one of those situations.

```
\documentclass{memoir}  

\makepagenote

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\chapter1{this is a chapter}

Text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote} text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote}

\chapter2{another chapter}

Text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote} text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote}

\printpagenotes 

\end{document}
```

And you get a ToC like

[image: ToC of the pagenotes issue]

Comment: Please add a minimal version of your document that shows the issue

Comment: \documentclass{memoir}  

\makepagenote

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\chapter1{this is a chapter}

Text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote} text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote}

\chapter2{another chapter}

Text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote} text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote}

\printpagenotes 

\end{document}

Comment: Please add the code to your question above -- you can edit the question ;-)

Comment: if you make it a section it will be part of chapter 2 but it not belong to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}` I changed the the original `\chapter` to `\chapter*`, thus preventing an automatic entry in the ToC. You could also use `\section*` but than it won't start on a new page etc.

In the line `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}` I manually add it to the ToC, please change "Notes" to whatever you like. If you do not want it in the ToC at all, just remove this line.

```
\documentclass{memoir}  

\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}}

\makepagenote

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\chapter{this is a chapter}

Text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote} text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote}

\chapter{another chapter}

Text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote} text text text.\pagenote{this is an endnote}

\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This migh no go well if the notes list is long, then the `\addcontentsline` will probably end up on the wrong page. Might be smarter with `\clearfochapter\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}`

Comment: Thanks wonderful stackers, it worked fine, with 120 endnotes in one chapter. I don't even want to know how you guys know this stuff, memman.pdf is brutal!

Comment: @daleif Thanks for pointing out this problem, I edit my code to avoid this.